# Префиксы для border-radius

Tags: css, border

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для border-radius нужны префиксы (-moz-border-radius,  -webkit-border-radius...) в 2022 году или уже нет? На "Can I use" и "MDN" не смог найти эту информацию.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=border-radius эм, жёлтые прямоугольнички же… В частности для Firefox это неактуально уже 10 лет

Comment: Увидел, спасибо.